# Why am I prompted to sign some of my CocoaPods in XCode 14?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode14, inappsettingskit

I opened up my project for the first time in a while, in XCode 14. It uses cocoapods, and always has. I now notice that two of my pods get an error prompt that they now have to be signed. See the image at the bottom.

I can see that the two libraries that XCode prompts for have duplicate entries, I think one is a static library and one is a framework.

However, I have no idea why this has started happening, nor why these two pods act differently than the rest.

If anyone knows why this has started happening now, or if there is anything I can do about it, I'm all ears. Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Signing is required for pods with resources. You can automate that by configuring your team identifier in the Podfile:

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.name == 'SDCAlertView-SDCAlertView'
            config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'XW6AHAD1DA'
        end
    end
end
```

Instead of `SDCAlertView-SDCAlertView` specify the InAppSettingsKit bundle target name and of course adjust your team identifier.

Alternatively, you may consider integrating InAppSettingsKit using Swift Package Manager where everything "just works".